# MYSQL - UNION Second dataset not returning results

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, union

So,

I have no idea what is going on. Both of these queries work fine running on their own. For some reason though when I attempt to UNION them together I only get data for the top query.

I would really appreciate some guidance on this. The second query basically returns results for data that is missing from the first query. I'm just not sure what is going on.

It is probably something simple I can't figure out, but I have tried quite a few different things and nothing seems to do the trick.

```
(SELECT

   date(dg.date) as 'Date',
   (pd.nid) as 'NID',
   if((bl.nid ) is not null,1,0) as 'Blocks',
   pd.special_weekday as 'Weekday Price',
   pd.special_weekend as 'Weekend Price',
   pd.special_weekly as 'Weekly Price',
   pd.special_minstay as 'Minimum Nights'
from (
   select DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL (@i:=@i+1)-1 DAY) as `Date`
   from information_schema.columns,(SELECT @i:=0) gen_sub 
   where (DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL @i DAY) BETWEEN curdate() AND date_add(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) 
) dg
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT  
n.nid as `nid`,
ifnull(p.special_from,p2.special_from) as `special_from`,
ifnull(p.special_to,p2.special_to) as 'special_to',
ifnull(p.special_weekdayprice,p2.special_weekdayprice) as `special_weekday`,
ifnull(p.special_weekendprice,p2.special_weekendprice) as `special_weekend`,
ifnull(p.special_weeklyprice,p2.special_weeklyprice) as `special_weekly`,
ifnull(p.special_minstay,p2.special_minstay) as `special_minstay`,
n.state_name as `state_name`

FROM 
radb.property_state_machine n 
LEFT JOIN radb.rep_property rep on n.nid=rep.parent
LEFT JOIN radb.rep_property rep1 on n.nid=rep1.nid
LEFT JOIN radb.price_dates p on n.nid=p.nid 
LEFT JOIN radb.price_dates p2 on rep1.parent=p2.nid 
WHERE n.state_name='Live' AND ( (rep.nid = 0 OR isnull(rep.nid)))) pd on ((pd.special_to IS NULL OR date(pd.special_to) >= dg.date)) AND (date(pd.special_from) <= dg.date )
LEFT JOIN
radb.node n on pd.nid=n.nid
LEFT JOIN
radb.profile_value pv on n.uid=pv.uid
LEFT JOIN
radb.admin_book bl  on ((date(bl.book_end) IS NULL OR date(bl.book_end) >= dg.date) and pd.nid=bl.nid) AND (date(bl.book_start) <= dg.date AND pd.nid=bl.nid)



GROUP BY 1,2)

UNION ALL



(SELECT

   date(dt.date) as 'Date',
    (tm.nid) as 'NID',
   if((tm.nid) is not null,1,0) as 'Blocks',
   null,
   null,
   null,
   null

FROM (
   select DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL (@i:=@i+1)-1 DAY) as `Date`
   from information_schema.columns,(SELECT @i:=0) gen_sub 
   where (DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL @i DAY) BETWEEN curdate() AND date_add(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) 
) dt
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT  
n1.nid as `nid`,
ifnull(m.book_start,m2.book_start) as `book_start`,
ifnull(m.book_end,m2.book_end) as `book_end`,
n1.state_name as `state_name`

FROM 
radb.property_state_machine n1
LEFT JOIN radb.rep_property rp on n1.nid=rp.parent
LEFT JOIN radb.rep_property rp1 on n1.nid=rp1.nid
LEFT JOIN radb.admin_book_temp m on n1.nid=m.nid 
LEFT JOIN radb.admin_book_temp m2 on rp1.parent=m2.nid 
WHERE n1.state_name='Live' AND ( (rp.nid = 0 OR isnull(rp.nid)))) tm  on ((date(tm.book_end) IS NULL OR date(tm.book_end) >= dt.date)  ) AND (date(tm.book_start) <= dt.date  ) 
LEFT JOIN
radb.node n2 on tm.nid=n2.nid
LEFT JOIN
radb.profile_value pv on n2.uid=pv.uid




GROUP BY 1,2)
```

VERSION 2 - Still the same issue even when I wrapped the UNION in a subselect

```
SELECT
 x.date as 'Date',
 x.NID as 'NID',
 x.blocks as 'Blocks',
 x.weekday as 'Weekday',
 x.weekend as 'Weekend',
 x.weekly as 'Weekly',
 x.min as 'Nights'
 FROM
   (SELECT date(dg.date) as 'Date',
   (pd.nid) as 'NID',
   if((bl.nid ) is not null,1,0) as 'Blocks',
   pd.special_weekday as 'Weekday',
   pd.special_weekend as 'Weekend',
   pd.special_weekly as 'Weekly',
   pd.special_minstay as 'min'
from (
   select DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL (@i:=@i+1)-1 DAY) as `Date`
   from information_schema.columns,(SELECT @i:=0) gen_sub 
   where (DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL @i DAY) BETWEEN curdate() AND date_add(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) 
) dg
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT  
n.nid as `nid`,
ifnull(p.special_from,p2.special_from) as `special_from`,
ifnull(p.special_to,p2.special_to) as 'special_to',
ifnull(p.special_weekdayprice,p2.special_weekdayprice) as `special_weekday`,
ifnull(p.special_weekendprice,p2.special_weekendprice) as `special_weekend`,
ifnull(p.special_weeklyprice,p2.special_weeklyprice) as `special_weekly`,
ifnull(p.special_minstay,p2.special_minstay) as `special_minstay`,
n.state_name as `state_name`

FROM 
radb.property_state_machine n 
LEFT JOIN radb.rep_property rep on n.nid=rep.parent
LEFT JOIN radb.rep_property rep1 on n.nid=rep1.nid
LEFT JOIN radb.price_dates p on n.nid=p.nid 
LEFT JOIN radb.price_dates p2 on rep1.parent=p2.nid 
WHERE n.state_name='Live' AND ( (rep.nid = 0 OR isnull(rep.nid)))) pd on ((pd.special_to IS NULL OR date(pd.special_to) >= dg.date)) AND (date(pd.special_from) <= dg.date )
LEFT JOIN
radb.admin_book bl  on ((date(bl.book_end) IS NULL OR date(bl.book_end) >= dg.date) and pd.nid=bl.nid) AND (date(bl.book_start) <= dg.date AND pd.nid=bl.nid)





UNION ALL
SELECT

   date(dt.date) as 'Date',
    (tm.nid) as 'NID',
   if((tm.nid) is not null,1,0) as 'Blocks',
   null as'Weekday',
   null as 'Weekend',
   null as 'Weekly',
   null as 'Nights'

FROM (
   select DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL (@i:=@i+1)-1 DAY) as `Date`
   from information_schema.columns,(SELECT @i:=0) gen_sub 
   where (DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL @i DAY) BETWEEN curdate() AND date_add(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) 
) dt
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT  
n.nid as `nid`,
ifnull(p.book_start,p2.book_start) as `book_start`,
ifnull(p.book_end,p2.book_end) as `book_end`,
n.state_name as `state_name`

FROM 
radb.property_state_machine n 
LEFT JOIN radb.rep_property rep on n.nid=rep.parent
LEFT JOIN radb.rep_property rep1 on n.nid=rep1.nid
LEFT JOIN radb.admin_book_temp p on n.nid=p.nid 
LEFT JOIN radb.admin_book_temp p2 on rep1.parent=p2.nid 
WHERE n.state_name='Live' AND ( (rep.nid = 0 OR isnull(rep.nid)))) tm  on ((date(tm.book_end) IS NULL OR date(tm.book_end) >= dt.date)  ) AND (date(tm.book_start) <= dt.date  ) 


 ) x
LEFT JOIN
radb.node n on x.nid=n.nid
LEFT JOIN
radb.profile_value pv on n.uid=pv.uid

GROUP BY x.date,x.nid,x.blocks,x.weekday,x.weekend,x.weekly,x.min
```

SAMPLE RESULTS

```
DATA SET #1

# Date, NID, Blocks, Weekday Price, Weekend Price, Weekly Price, Minimum Nights
'2018-10-05', '190668', '1', '165', '165', '165', '3'
'2018-10-05', '190669', '1', '235', '235', '231', '2'
'2018-10-05', '190671', '0', '176', '133', '142', '2'
'2018-10-05', '190672', '1', '661', '661', '658', '4'
'2018-10-05', '190673', '1', '203', '203', '138', '2'
'2018-10-05', '190675', '1', '219', '219', '158', '4'
'2018-10-05', '190676', '1', '204', '204', '197', '3'
'2018-10-05', '190677', '1', '235', '235', '217', '3'


DATA SET #2

# Date, NID, Blocks, Weekday Price, Weekend Price, Weekly Price, Minimum Nights
'2018-10-05', '190670', '1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
'2018-10-06', '190670', '1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
'2018-10-05', '190680', '1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
'2018-10-05', '190885', '1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
'2018-10-06', '190885', '1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
'2018-10-05', '190933', '1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
'2018-10-05', '191063', '1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
'2018-10-06', '191063', '1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

Basically these two data sets should be appended as the second data set fills in missing gaps of data set 1. Second data set would not have data for the last 4 columns.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Hi, I added a sample data set for your viewing.

Comment: @D-Shih Forgot to tag you.

Comment: For starters, please use Explicit column names/aliases in Group By, not like `1,2`. It is non-standard and error prone.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Thanks for the response, I've tried that as well. No luck...

Comment: @Jalal.Hassan if you can create a SQL Fiddle for this. I can give it a try.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I solved my issues thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,

After ruminating over this logic for a few hours and doing some trial and error I realized it was not able to union because of my generated date subquery. Because of that I redid the logic behind how the query ran.

Below is my working SQL. Thanks for the help everyone.

```
SELECT 
b.nid as 'NID',
dg.date as 'Date',
if((bl.nid is not null) or isnull(b.weekday), 1,0) as 'Blocks',
b.weekday as 'Weekday',
b.weekend as 'Weekend',
b.weekly as 'Weekly',
b.nights as 'Nights'
as 'Nights'

FROM
(
   select DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL (@i:=@i+1)-1 DAY) as `Date`
   from information_schema.columns,(SELECT @i:=0) gen_sub 
   where (DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL @i DAY) BETWEEN curdate() AND date_add(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) 
) dg
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT


   (pd.nid) as 'NID',
   pd.special_from as 'start',
   pd.special_to as 'end',
   pd.special_weekday as 'Weekday',
   pd.special_weekend as 'Weekend',
   pd.special_weekly as 'Weekly',
   pd.special_minstay as 'Nights'
from 

(SELECT  
n.nid as `nid`,
ifnull(p.special_from,p2.special_from) as `special_from`,
ifnull(p.special_to,p2.special_to) as 'special_to',
ifnull(p.special_weekdayprice,p2.special_weekdayprice) as `special_weekday`,
ifnull(p.special_weekendprice,p2.special_weekendprice) as `special_weekend`,
ifnull(p.special_weeklyprice,p2.special_weeklyprice) as `special_weekly`,
ifnull(p.special_minstay,p2.special_minstay) as `special_minstay`,
n.state_name as `state_name`

FROM 
radb.property_state_machine n 
LEFT JOIN radb.rep_property rep on n.nid=rep.parent
LEFT JOIN radb.rep_property rep1 on n.nid=rep1.nid
LEFT JOIN radb.price_dates p on n.nid=p.nid 
LEFT JOIN radb.price_dates p2 on rep1.parent=p2.nid 
WHERE ( (rep.nid = 0 OR isnull(rep.nid)))) pd 





UNION ALL



SELECT


    (tm.nid) as 'NID',
    tm.book_start as 'start',
    tm.book_end as 'end',
   null,
   null,
   null,
   null

FROM 
(SELECT 
nd2.nid as 'nid',
ifnull(t.book_start,t2.book_start) as `book_start`,
ifnull(t.book_end,t2.book_end) as `book_end`
FROM radb.property_state_machine nd2
LEFT JOIN radb.rep_property rp on nd2.nid=rp.parent
LEFT JOIN radb.rep_property rp1 on nd2.nid=rp1.nid
LEFT JOIN radb.admin_book_temp t on nd2.nid=t.nid 
LEFT JOIN radb.admin_book_temp t2 on rp1.parent=t2.nid where ((rp.nid = 0 OR isnull(rp.nid)))
 ) tm  



) b on ((b.end IS NULL OR date(b.end) >= dg.date)) AND (date(b.start) <= dg.date )
LEFT JOIN
radb.admin_book bl on ((date(bl.book_end) IS NULL OR date(bl.book_end) >= dg.date) and bl.nid=b.nid) AND (date(bl.book_start) <= dg.date AND bl.nid=b.nid)
LEFT JOIN
radb.property_state_machine psm on b.nid=psm.nid

where psm.state_name='Live'

GROUP BY 1,2
FROM
(
   select DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL (@i:=@i+1)-1 DAY) as `Date`
   from information_schema.columns,(SELECT @i:=0) gen_sub 
   where (DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL @i DAY) BETWEEN curdate() AND date_add(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) 
) dg
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT


   (pd.nid) as 'NID',
   pd.special_from as 'start',
   pd.special_to as 'end',
   pd.special_weekday as 'Weekday',
   pd.special_weekend as 'Weekend',
   pd.special_weekly as 'Weekly',
   pd.special_minstay as 'Nights'
from 

(SELECT  
n.nid as `nid`,
ifnull(p.special_from,p2.special_from) as `special_from`,
ifnull(p.special_to,p2.special_to) as 'special_to',
ifnull(p.special_weekdayprice,p2.special_weekdayprice) as `special_weekday`,
ifnull(p.special_weekendprice,p2.special_weekendprice) as `special_weekend`,
ifnull(p.special_weeklyprice,p2.special_weeklyprice) as `special_weekly`,
ifnull(p.special_minstay,p2.special_minstay) as `special_minstay`,
n.state_name as `state_name`

FROM 
radb.property_state_machine n 
LEFT JOIN radb.rep_property rep on n.nid=rep.parent
LEFT JOIN radb.rep_property rep1 on n.nid=rep1.nid
LEFT JOIN radb.price_dates p on n.nid=p.nid 
LEFT JOIN radb.price_dates p2 on rep1.parent=p2.nid 
WHERE ( (rep.nid = 0 OR isnull(rep.nid)))) pd 





UNION ALL



SELECT


    (tm.nid) as 'NID',
    tm.book_start as 'start',
    tm.book_end as 'end',
   null,
   null,
   null,
   null

FROM 
(SELECT 
nd2.nid as 'nid',
ifnull(t.book_start,t2.book_start) as `book_start`,
ifnull(t.book_end,t2.book_end) as `book_end`
FROM radb.property_state_machine nd2
LEFT JOIN radb.rep_property rp on nd2.nid=rp.parent
LEFT JOIN radb.rep_property rp1 on nd2.nid=rp1.nid
LEFT JOIN radb.admin_book_temp t on nd2.nid=t.nid 
LEFT JOIN radb.admin_book_temp t2 on rp1.parent=t2.nid where ((rp.nid = 0 OR isnull(rp.nid)))
 ) tm  



) b on ((b.end IS NULL OR date(b.end) >= dg.date)) AND (date(b.start) <= dg.date )
LEFT JOIN
radb.admin_book bl on ((date(bl.book_end) IS NULL OR date(bl.book_end) >= dg.date) and bl.nid=b.nid) AND (date(bl.book_start) <= dg.date AND bl.nid=b.nid)
LEFT JOIN
radb.property_state_machine psm on b.nid=psm.nid

where psm.state_name='Live'

GROUP BY 1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think you should have the same column names in both the tables.

```
(SELECT

   date(dg.date) as 'Date',
   (pd.nid) as 'NID',
   if((bl.nid ) is not null,1,0) as 'Blocks',
   pd.special_weekday as 'Weekday Price',
   pd.special_weekend as 'Weekend Price',
   pd.special_weekly as 'Weekly Price',
   pd.special_minstay as 'Minimum Nights'
from (
   select DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL (@i:=@i+1)-1 DAY) as `Date`
   from information_schema.columns,(SELECT @i:=0) gen_sub 
   where (DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL @i DAY) BETWEEN curdate() AND date_add(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) 
) dg
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT  
n.nid as `nid`,
ifnull(p.special_from,p2.special_from) as `special_from`,
ifnull(p.special_to,p2.special_to) as 'special_to',
ifnull(p.special_weekdayprice,p2.special_weekdayprice) as `special_weekday`,
ifnull(p.special_weekendprice,p2.special_weekendprice) as `special_weekend`,
ifnull(p.special_weeklyprice,p2.special_weeklyprice) as `special_weekly`,
ifnull(p.special_minstay,p2.special_minstay) as `special_minstay`,
n.state_name as `state_name`

FROM 
radb.property_state_machine n 
LEFT JOIN radb.rep_property rep on n.nid=rep.parent
LEFT JOIN radb.rep_property rep1 on n.nid=rep1.nid
LEFT JOIN radb.price_dates p on n.nid=p.nid 
LEFT JOIN radb.price_dates p2 on rep1.parent=p2.nid 
WHERE n.state_name='Live' AND ( (rep.nid = 0 OR isnull(rep.nid)))) pd on ((pd.special_to IS NULL OR date(pd.special_to) >= dg.date)) AND (date(pd.special_from) <= dg.date )
LEFT JOIN
radb.node n on pd.nid=n.nid
LEFT JOIN
radb.profile_value pv on n.uid=pv.uid
LEFT JOIN
radb.admin_book bl  on ((date(bl.book_end) IS NULL OR date(bl.book_end) >= dg.date) and pd.nid=bl.nid) AND (date(bl.book_start) <= dg.date AND pd.nid=bl.nid)



GROUP BY 1,2)

UNION ALL



(SELECT

   date(dt.date) as 'Date',
    (tm.nid) as 'NID',
   if((tm.nid) is not null,1,0) as 'Blocks',
   null as 'Weekday Price',
   null as 'Weekend Price',
   null as 'Weekly Price',
   null as 'Minimum Nights'

FROM (
   select DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL (@i:=@i+1)-1 DAY) as `Date`
   from information_schema.columns,(SELECT @i:=0) gen_sub 
   where (DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL @i DAY) BETWEEN curdate() AND date_add(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) 
) dt
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT  
n1.nid as `nid`,
ifnull(m.book_start,m2.book_start) as `book_start`,
ifnull(m.book_end,m2.book_end) as `book_end`,
n1.state_name as `state_name`

FROM 
radb.property_state_machine n1
LEFT JOIN radb.rep_property rp on n1.nid=rp.parent
LEFT JOIN radb.rep_property rp1 on n1.nid=rp1.nid
LEFT JOIN radb.admin_book_temp m on n1.nid=m.nid 
LEFT JOIN radb.admin_book_temp m2 on rp1.parent=m2.nid 
WHERE n1.state_name='Live' AND ( (rp.nid = 0 OR isnull(rp.nid)))) tm  on ((date(tm.book_end) IS NULL OR date(tm.book_end) >= dt.date)  ) AND (date(tm.book_start) <= dt.date  ) 
LEFT JOIN
radb.node n2 on tm.nid=n2.nid
LEFT JOIN
radb.profile_value pv on n2.uid=pv.uid




GROUP BY 1,2)
```

Comment: I have already tried done that, generally you don't need the columns to be named if they are placeholders like  a null. In my experience